# mailto X-Frame-Options error

Tags: html, mailto

i got following error when i click on mailto: link in colorbox.
its work without color box, but unfortunately i need to use color box.

i tried header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); but it does't work.
and it show following error message in console.

```
 Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the `mailto` as the primary link for the lightbox (or I guess we're calling them colorboxes now), or as a caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never messed with X-Frame-Options (though I did work directly for the guy that wrote the book on clickjacking).  According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header), there are only two acceptable values:

- DENY
- SAMEORIGIN

And these are returned by the iframed source server, which it sounds like you have control over.  Both of which are defensive, not permissive.

What happens if you turn off the header outright?

Also, to avoid issues with users who use their web mail client (like me) who may not want to leave the colorbox or have the webmail client bound in an iframe, try setting `target="_blank"` on the link.  Perhaps escaping the iframe will alleviate other issues.

Comment: nw i propose to design team to make the link in new tab or either make it parent. hopefully it can be fix

Answer (score 0):

Some sites forbid their pages from being displayed in an iframe.  If that is the situation you are running into, then there isn't much that can be done.  However, I would not recommend trying to colorbox an mailto link, as you have no control over how a visitors handle those kinds of links.

Comment: but my 1 is mailto:
nw i propose to design team to make the link in new tab or either make it parent